# Javascript/jQuery Click Element within Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

This is probably something quite **easy** to resolve, but for some reason, I can't figure it out.

I have the following HTML:

```
<li onclick="function_1();">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="function_2();">
  <div onclick="function_3();">
</li>
```

My issue is: Whenever I click one of the child elements (either the checkbox or div), it also carries out the function from the `<li>` -->  `function_1()`.

How can I prevent the parent element function from being called when child element is being clicked?  What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [stopPropagation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) function

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can just `return false` from the child elements onclick function.