# Using JQuery, how do I stop click events propagating up the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following HTML snippet:

```
<li class="list">
  <img src="/assets/img/site/arrow_black.png"/>My List Element<span class="star"></span>
</li>
```

When I bind a click event to the `li` element and also bind a click event to the `.star` class, my question is the following:

**How do I stop the click event on the `li` firing when I click on the star?**

My JQuery code looks something along the lines of:

```
$(".list").click(function() {
//do something
}

$(".star").click(function() {
//do something
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript/jQuery Click Element within Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408138/javascript-jquery-click-element-within-element)

Comment: and many others, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164213/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-on-checkbox-click and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460197/jquery-disabling-click-function-on-parent-element/3460215#3460215

Comment: lol, maybe jQuery needs more documentation on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [jQuery.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$(".star").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // do work
}
```

Comment: +1 for being the first person to put up an example without an error in it.

Comment: lol, wow thought i'd get that up there first, guess i'm gettin slow in my old age, and ty @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1):

Try [`event.stopPropagation();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$(".star").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the even propgagation for .star.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

```
$(".star").click(function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event delegation ..

Apply the event listener to the ul

```
document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click",function(e) {

if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
    var classes = e.target.className.split(" ");

    if(classes) {

      for(var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {

        if(classes[x] == "star") { // do your thing
                                  }
                    }
          }
  }
});

});
```

or just use preventDefault to star class